# When the user browse the link http://mysite/#abc , how to make the browser scroll to <a name="abc"></a>

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am renewing a web site. An anchor `<a name="abc"></a>` in the old version web page, when the user browses the link http://mysite/#abc, the browser would scroll to  section.

When I migrate the web page to react, it does not work again.
Unfortunately, there is no navigation section on the web page, so I cannot use `<LINK>` element to do the job.

Here is my original code:

```
    <Container fluid>
        <Row>
            <Col className="fs-3 fw-bold text-center">
                Table caption
            </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Col>
                <InputGroup className="my-1">
                    <InputGroup.Text><Search /></InputGroup.Text>
                    <FormControl onChange={search} placeholder="Search" type="search" value={keyword}/>
                </InputGroup>
            </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Col>
                ..............
            </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <Col>
                <a name="abc"></abc>
                <ABC/>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </Container>
```

I have tried to replace

```
<a name="abc"></abc>
<ABC/>
```

with

```
<section id="abc" name="abc">
  <ABC/>
</section>
```

However, it still does not work.
Would you help to fix the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Scroll Into View](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) for it.

To do this you can use useRef hook

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
```

Create a ref

```
const abcRef = useRef();
```

Give the ref to your element
Element would look like this:

```
<a name="abc" ref={abcRef}></a>
```

Then when page is loaded, you can use this:

```
abcRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
```

But before that you have to check url hash whether it has 'abc' or not. Complete code would be something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (window.location.hash === '#abc') {
      abcRef.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' })
    }
  }, []);
```